# Dual boot ubuntu and windows 8.1 hangs

Tags: boot, windows-8, freeze

I have dual booted my laptop with ubuntu and windows. The problem is that windows 8 shows 100% disk usage and while running ubuntu, the cooler runs too fast, proably using more hardware resources and it lags sometime. Is this because of the disk partitions or anything else? Please help

Answer (score 0):

When you log in to windows 8, it tries to index some data. After working with your windows for a while, the data will become bigger and bigger and it cause a high and noticeable disk usage.

Ubuntu is not as optimal as windows 8 in resource managing. In addition, there can be a problem with your GPU driver. If you didn't install that, [take a tour here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120955/ubuntu-14-04-nvidia-proprietary-drivers-installation/176546#176546). It could help a lot in controlling the temperature.

Don't worry, there is nothing wrong with having a dual boot system.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I was wondering if it was because of some bad sector or what it's called. Like the partition fragmented and so the disk was running 100%. But I tried disk degragmentation in windows but it showed the disk was not fragmented